# onclick passing numbers and strings

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I put a string value into an onclick the console returns 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'? It works fine if its just a number but not if its a string!

Code:

```
document.getElementById("productMenu").innerHTML += "<div class=\"leftMenuItems\"    onclick=\"javascript:showResources(" + p_codes + ");\">" + p_codes + " - " + p_names + "</div>";

<div class="leftMenuItems" onclick="javascript:showResources(1234ABC);">Product Name</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes

```
onclick="javascript:showResources('1234ABC');"
```

because `1234ABC` is a string, while numbers don't need quotes

Comment: Doh! sometimes the obvious is just not obvious! working now! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you don't wrap the argument in quote marks, JavaScript is looking for a variable of the same name. Since variable names cannot begin with number literals, you're receiving the error. Numbers alone will be passed in as integers.

You should use the following:

```
<div class="leftMenuItems" onclick="javascript:showResources('1234ABC');">Product Name</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation, one day I will get better at all this... One day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me.

Pass string inside of quote in the following string.format:
`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("'"+personnelPhotoList[j].name.Trim()+"'")`

Code sample:

```
StringBuilder strPhotos = new StringBuilder();

strPhotos.Append(String.Format("<div class=\"div_employee_img\">
         <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"DeletePhoto({0}); return true;\"></a></div>,   
         HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("'"+personnelPhotoList[j].name.Trim()+"'")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it did not post complete code, here it is again

`strPhotos.Append(String.Format("<input type=\"button\" onclick = \"Delete({0}) return false;\", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("'"+personnelPhotoList[j].name.Trim()+"'")));`